# How to convert PropertyValueCollection into a List C# ? (ResultPropertyCollection and SearchResult)

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've written a query to read some stuff from Active Directory, but the result is some kind of "ResultPropertyCollection", which is something I'm not familiar with.

How can I convert this result to a list (like Generic List) that I'm more familiar with so I can do something with the results?

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.rootLDAP);
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(& (objectcategory=Group))");
    
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccounttype");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("grouptype");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectcategory");
     
     var r = ( from SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll() select sr ) .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only want a list of `SearchResult` types, you could use:

```
var r = ds.FindAll();
        
List<SearchResult> results = new List<SearchResult>();

foreach (SearchResult sr in r)
{
   results.Add(sr);
}
```

But since you want the actual values from the search results, you need to do more work.

Basically, that collection contains all the properties you've defined for the search - at least as long as they contain a value!

So really, what you need to do is create a class to hold those values. The two elements `memberOf` and `member` can themselves contain multiple values (they're "multi-valued" attributes in AD) - so you'll need a list of strings for these:

```
public class YourType
{
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public int SamAccountType { get; set; }
    public int GroupType { get; set; }
    public string ObjectCategory { get; set; }
    public List<string> MemberOf { get; set; }
    public List<string> Member { get; set; }
}
```

Then, once you have your search result, you need to iterate over the results and create new instances of `YourType` for each search result, and stick those into a `List<YourType>`:

```
foreach(SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
{
    YourType newRecord = ConvertToYourType(sr);
}
```

and in that method, you need to inspect the `.Properties` collection for each value and extract it:

```
public YourType ConvertToYourType(SearchResult result)
{
    YourType returnValue = new YourType();
    returnValue.MemberOf = new List<string>();
    returnValue.Member = new List<string>();

    if(result.Properties["samAccountName"] != null && result.Properties["samAccountName"].Count > 0)
    {
       returnValue.SamAccountName = result.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();
    }

    // ..... and so on for each of your values you need to extract

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of MemberOf and Member for the returnValue?

Comment: Would you be able to just do `if(result.Properties["samAccountName"]) {}`? That would check for whether there is at least one result (granted, that might not have been available in 2011).

Answer (score 4):

I was also confused at first, but it was all matter of getting the type of the property collection item. Once I found out that the type of the properties item is System.Collections.DictionaryEntry and that the value is a collection made out of ResultPropertyValueCollection items, simple iterations were possible.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
        bool attemptResult = false;
        string ldap = "LDAP:<Your A.D. specific connection string>";
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";
            SearchResult one = searcher.FindOne();
            attemptResult = true;
            string properties = "";
            string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(one.Properties);
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry de in one.Properties) {
                properties += (properties.Length > 0 ? ",\n" : "");
                properties += "\"" + de.Key + "\": [";
                ResultPropertyValueCollection vc = ((ResultPropertyValueCollection)de.Value);
                foreach (var val in vc) {
                    properties += "{\"type\": \"" + val.GetType().Name + "\", \"value\"; \"" + val.ToString() + "\"}";
                }
                properties += "]";
            }
            properties = properties.Replace("}{", "},{");

            string displayName = one.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
            string givenName = one.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();
            string lastname =  one.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //log the error;
        }            
        return attemptResult;
```

Notice the fast and easy conversion to string using JsonConvert.SerializeObject. This a one step conversion.

I also performed a personalized conversion to string by using foreach iterations. This was more a self-teaching exercise from wich I get that after I get the value for a named property, I can find out whether the properties has zero, one or more values and act accordingly, even validating the object type if it were necessary.

Here is the value obtained in both string variables, properties and userData (Some items removed for privacy).

```
/* Value of userData Obtained with Json serializator*/

{"givenname":["First Name"],"samaccountname":["User.Name"],"cn":["First Name Last Name"],"pwdlastset":[131641282827115142],"whencreated":["2017-10-12T22:16:43"],"badpwdcount":[0],"displayname":["First Name Last Name"],"lastlogon":[131648243091569908],"samaccounttype":[805306368],"countrycode":[0],"objectguid":["SOMETHINGBASE64LIKE=="],"usnchanged":[52144153],"manager":["CN=The Name Of A Person,OU=Department Name,OU=City,OU=GroupName ,DC=Domain,DC=com"],"whenchanged":["2018-03-02T23:21:54"],"name":["First Name Last Name"],"objectsid":["SOMETHINGBASE64LIKE=="],"lastlogoff":[0],"lockouttime":[0],"badpasswordtime":[131647632246625185],"instancetype":[4],"primarygroupid":[513],"objectcategory":["CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com"],"logoncount":[1073],"useraccountcontrol":[512],"description":["Some text"],"dscorepropagationdata":["1601-01-01T00:00:00"],"distinguishedname":["CN=First Name Last Name,OU=Department Name,OU=City,OU=GroupName ,DC=Domain,DC=com"],"objectclass":["top","person","organizationalPerson","user"],"adspath":["LDAP://Server/CN=First Name Last Name,OU=Department Name,OU=City,OU=GroupName ,DC=Domain,DC=com"],"usncreated":[39705915],"lastlogontimestamp":[131643676396776065],"userprincipalname":["User.Name@Domain.com"],"employeeid":["99999"],"accountexpires":[9223372036854775807],"department":["DepartmentName"],"codepage":[0],"sn":["Last Name"]}

/* value of properties, the string I concatenated */
"givenname": [{"type": "String", "value"; "First Name"}],
"samaccountname": [{"type": "String", "value"; "User.Name"}],
"cn": [{"type": "String", "value"; "First Name Last name"}],
"pwdlastset": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "131641282827115142"}],
"whencreated": [{"type": "DateTime", "value"; "12/10/2017 10:16:43 p. m."}],
"badpwdcount": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "0"}],
"displayname": [{"type": "String", "value"; "First Name Last name"}],
"lastlogon": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "131648243091569908"}],
"samaccounttype": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "805306368"}],
"countrycode": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "0"}],
"objectguid": [{"type": "Byte[]", "value"; "System.Byte[]"}],
"usnchanged": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "52144153"}],
"manager": [{"type": "String", "value"; "CN=Some Person Name,OU=Department name,OU=City,OU=Group Name,DC=Domain,DC=com"}],
"whenchanged": [{"type": "DateTime", "value"; "2/3/2018 11:21:54 p. m."}],
"name": [{"type": "String", "value"; "First Name Last name"}],
"objectsid": [{"type": "Byte[]", "value"; "System.Byte[]"}],
"lastlogoff": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "0"}],
"lockouttime": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "0"}],
"badpasswordtime": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "131647632246625185"}],
"instancetype": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "4"}],
"primarygroupid": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "513"}],
"objectcategory": [{"type": "String", "value"; "CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com"}],
"logoncount": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "1073"}],
"useraccountcontrol": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "512"}],
"description": [{"type": "String", "value"; "13065, PROGRAMADOR SENIOR"}],
"dscorepropagationdata": [{"type": "DateTime", "value"; "1/1/1601 12:00:00 a. m."}],
"distinguishedname": [{"type": "String", "value"; "CN=First Name Last name,OU=Department name,OU=City,OU=Group Name,DC=Domain,DC=com"}],
"objectclass": [{"type": "String", "value"; "top"},{"type": "String", "value"; "person"},{"type": "String", "value"; "organizationalPerson"},{"type": "String", "value"; "user"}],
"adspath": [{"type": "String", "value"; "LDAP://SERVERNAME/CN=First Name Last name,OU=Department name,OU=City,OU=Group Name,DC=Domain,DC=com"}],
"usncreated": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "39705915"}],
"lastlogontimestamp": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "131643676396776065"}],
"userprincipalname": [{"type": "String", "value"; "User.Name@Domain.com"}],
"employeeid": [{"type": "String", "value"; "13065"}],
"accountexpires": [{"type": "Int64", "value"; "9223372036854775807"}],
"department": [{"type": "String", "value"; "IT"}],
"codepage": [{"type": "Int32", "value"; "0"}],
"sn": [{"type": "String", "value"; "Last name"}]
```

As you can see, some of the properties have more than one value. So, to get a simple generic list of properties you would need to decide what to do with multi-valued properties. Most likely, you'd like to have all values as strings, so, multiple values can simply be concatenated using a suitable separator.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be a complete solution or the proper answer.
Below is only a solution to convert `SearchResultCollection` to `List`

```
SearchResultCollection rc = ds.FindAll();

List<SearchResult> resultList = rc.Cast<SearchResult>().ToList();

// Now loop through the list
foreach(SearchResult sr in resultList)
{
    //.. get properties here
}
```

Comment: The `SearchResultCollection` class does not have `Cast` as an available function, so this will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Can't we use something like this? (As I am currently using it)

```
ds.FindAll().Cast<SearchResult>().Select(result => new Address(result.GetDirectoryEntry())).ToList();

public class Address
{
    internal Address(DirectoryEntry entry)
    {
        //
        // You can get one or more of the following properties:
        //
        //
        // objectClass
        // cn
        // description
        // givenName
        // distinguishedName
        // instanceType
        // whenCreated
        // whenChanged
        // displayName
        // uSNCreated
        // memberOf
        // uSNChanged
        // homeMTA
        // proxyAddresses
        // homeMDB
        // mDBUseDefaults
        // mailNickname
        // protocolSettings
        // name
        // objectGUID
        // userAccountControl
        // badPwdCount
        // codePage
        // countryCode
        // badPasswordTime
        // lastLogon
        // pwdLastSet
        // primaryGroupID
        // objectSid
        // accountExpires
        // logonCount
        // sAMAccountName
        // sAMAccountType
        // showInAddressBook
        // legacyExchangeDN
        // userPrincipalName
        // lockoutTime
        // objectCategory
        // dSCorePropagationData
        // lastLogonTimestamp
        // textEncodedORAddress
        // mail
        // msExchPoliciesExcluded
        // msExchMailboxTemplateLink
        // msExchRecipientDisplayType
        // msExchUserCulture
        // msExchVersion
        // msExchRecipientTypeDetails
        // msExchHomeServerName
        // msExchALObjectVersion
        // msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor
        // msExchUserAccountControl
        // msExchMailboxGuid
        // nTSecurityDescriptor

        // As an example we get only two properties
        this.DisplayName = (string)entry.Properties["displayName"].Value;
        this.Mail = (string)entry.Properties["mail"].Value;
        Manager = (string)entry.Properties["manager"].Value;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Manager
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Mail
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is `Cast` definition available for the `SearchResultsCollection` class.